# How to get an xpath of element in the table

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm getting started with Selenium webdriver (newbie :D). How i can get an xpath of element in the table? I have tried to see the source code of page in chrome, after - pick element and get xpath of it. Selenium webdriver tells me that he can't find an element with this xpath.

Link of the page:
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList

How i can paste characters to textBox, for example?
I tried to use this code:

UPD:

```
 @org.junit.Test
    public void getStarted(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/fedor/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList");

        WebElement t = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//tr[td[contains(text(), 'First Name')]]//input"));

        t.clear();
        t.sendKeys("test1111");

    }
```

UPD 2: Problem was in miss of implicit wait before finding element. This code fixed it for me:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: What is your xpath expression? You are probably getting too many results and therefore Selenium throws an exception. Try `findElements()` method and iterating through its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example from the given [link](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList).

If you want to enter text into **First Name** `textBox` try using below `xpath` which would locate appropriate `textBox` using text :-

```
.//tr[td[normalize-space() = 'First Name:']]//input
```

or

```
.//tr[td[contains(text(), 'First Name')]]//input
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check it. Your selectors don't work for me (

Comment: @FedorKostjuchenko Add some implicit wait before finding element and try